# Slidable widget taking too much size flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, checkbox

I'm working on a todo App and I display my todos with some kinda cards and I'm using the slidable widget to modify or delete them. The problem is that the left slide takes too much space and is above my checkbox. That's a picture of it:

[image: slidable]

[image: slidable 2]

I don't really know why it's like that so if you have some idea please tell me.

```
 return ClipRRect(
  borderRadius : BorderRadius.circular(15),
  child: Slidable(
    actionPane: SlidableDrawerActionPane(),
    key: Key(widget.todo.id),
    actions: [
      IconSlideAction(
        color: Colors.green,
        onTap: () {},
        caption: 'Edit',
        icon: Icons.edit,
      )
    ],
    secondaryActions: [
      IconSlideAction(
        color: Colors.red,
        caption: 'Delete',
        onTap: () {},
        icon: Icons.delete,
      )
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Update, I just needed to add some padding to my checkbox :

```
padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
```